# Basic Inner Joins - Understanding

Tags: sql

I usually learn by seeing examples and working my way backwards.

Can someone help me write out this query:

https://www.sqlteaching.com/#!multiple_joins

This is what I wrote, I do not know what I am doing wrong:

```
SELECT character.name, actor.name
FROM character 
INNER JOIN character_tv_show
ON character.id = character_tv_show.character_id
INNER JOIN character_actor
ON actor.id = character_actor.actor_id;
```

Comment: Figured it out:

SELECT character.name, actor.name
FROM character 
INNER JOIN character_actor
ON character.id = character_actor.character_id
INNER JOIN actor
ON character_actor.actor_id = actor.id;

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing the `actor` table in both the select list, and in the second inner join, but you never include the table in the query.

Comment: Then why doesn't this work:

SELECT character.name, actor.name
FROM character 
INNER JOIN character_tv_show
ON character.id = character_tv_show.character_id
INNER JOIN actor
ON actor.id = character_actor.actor_id;

Comment: Same reason, but with a different table.  Now you're referencing the `character_actor` table without including it in the query.

Comment: Got it!SELECT character.name, actor.name
FROM character 
INNER JOIN character_actor
ON character.id = character_actor.character_id
INNER JOIN actor
ON character_actor.actor_id = actor.id;

Comment: Thanks for your help RJM!